How can I fix "No such file or directory" when compiling a CEF application?
I’m trying to compile a CEF-based kiosk application on Linux (Pop!_OS 22.04) using the cef_binary_131.3.5+g573cec5+chromium-131.0.6778.205_linux64 package. My main.cpp includes the cef_app.h file:
#include "cef_app.h"

I’m compiling with the following command:
g++ -o FOSSKiosk main.cpp \
    -I/path/to/cef/include \
    -L/path/to/cef/Release \
    -lcef -lcef_dll_wrapper \
    -pthread



However, I get this error:
fatal error: cef_app.h: No such file or directory



What I’ve Tried:

Verified that cef_app.h is located in /path/to/cef/include/cef_app.h.
Ensured that -I/path/to/cef/include is correct.
Checked file permissions for the include directory and ensured they are readable.



Environment Details:

OS: Pop!_OS 22.04 (Linux)
GCC Version: 11.3.0
CEF Version: cef_binary_131.3.5+g573cec5+chromium-131.0.6778.205_linux64

Any guidance on resolving this issue would be appreciated!

All these fake /path/to/cef and non verbatim and not complete error message make the question unanswerable.
